# CASE WHEN using AND statement in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query like this :

```
SELECT  
    CASE 
       WHEN (CONVERT(INT, (datepart(DD, A.CIDATE))) AND Year(getDate()) = 2016 ) <= 15
          THEN CONVERT(INT,(datepart(MM,A.CIDATE)))  
       WHEN CONVERT(INT, (datepart(DD, A.CIDATE))) > 15
          THEN CONVERT(INT, (datepart(MM, A.CIDATE))) + 1
       ELSE 0
    END AS MASA_PAJAK
FROM
    V_CLAIM_INTERNAL A
```

It's working but when I add **AND Year(getDate()) = 2016** it throws an error:

> Msg 4145, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'AND'.

I try to make convert also but still having the same error.

```
  SELECT 
      CASE 
         WHEN ((CONVERT(INT, (datepart(DD, A.CIDATE))) AND (convert(int, Year(getDate()) = 2016 ))) <= 15  
            THEN CONVERT(INT, (datepart(MM, A.CIDATE))) 
         WHEN CONVERT(INT, (datepart(DD, A.CIDATE))) > 15 
            THEN CONVERT(INT, (datepart(MM, A.CIDATE))) + 1 
         ELSE 0  
      END AS MASA_PAJAK
  FROM         
      V_CLAIM_INTERNAL A
```

What is my query mistake :?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably what you are intending to do:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN DATEPART(DD, A.CIDATE) <= 15 AND YEAR(GETDATE()) = 2016
            THEN DATEPART(MM, A.CIDATE)
            WHEN DATEPART(DD, A.CIDATE) > 15
            THEN DATEPART(MM, A.CIDATE) + 1
            ELSE 0
       END AS MASA_PAJAK
FROM V_CLAIM_INTERNAL A
```

Note that you *don't* need to convert/cast the result of calling `DATEPART`, because it already returns an integer.

Comment: it's work.. thank you so much.. Thank you also for your explanation  :)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  CASE 
            WHEN (CONVERT(INT,(datepart(DD,A.CIDATE)))<= 15 AND Year(getDate()) = 2016 )   THEN  CONVERT(INT,(datepart(MM,A.CIDATE)))  
            WHEN  CONVERT(INT,(datepart(DD,A.CIDATE))) > 15 THEN CONVERT(INT,(datepart(MM,A.CIDATE)))+1
        ELSE 0  END AS MASA_PAJAK
FROM    V_CLAIM_INTERNAL A
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this Query:

```
SELECT  CASE WHEN datepart(DD,A.CIDATE)<= 15 AND
              Year(getDate()) = 2016 
         THEN datepart(MM,A.CIDATE)
         WHEN datepart(DD,A.CIDATE) > 15
         THEN datepart(MM,A.CIDATE) + 1
         ELSE 0
    END AS MASA_PAJAK
FROM V_CLAIM_INTERNAL A
```